# Is it possible to use a capacitor to cool the surrounding medium by pulling its plates apart while remaining connected to the battery?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, capacitance

Considering a parallel plate capacitor connected to a battery. If plates are pulled apart heat is not produced. But the battery is absorbing energy as it gets charged. So heat is absorbed. If this is done, will the surrounding area get cooled?

Comment: "the battery is absorbing energy as it gets charged. So is heat is absorbed." I think you have a flaw in this logical jump here. Energy is absorbed doesn't mean heat is absorbed - there are many forms of energy. When charging a battery the energy is stored in some sort of potential energy (e.g. chemical energy).

Comment: And since nothing is 100% efficient, the charging process will usually radiate heat - not absorb it. This is why devices that are charging tend to heat up.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it satisfactorily answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding area will, in general, be heated since no process is 100% efficient. When the plates are pulled apart, current flows to the battery's electrodes where it donate or accept electrons creating ions. The energy is stored in these higher energy ionic states, not as heat.